# How do I convert this into lambda

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have this list of list of list (apologies for the hideous code)
How can I covert this into Lambda?

```
List<EmailAddressInformationDataType> emailInfoDataList = workerType.getWorkerData().getPersonalData().getContactData().getEmailAddressDatas();

for(EmailAddressInformationDataType infoData : emailInfoDataList)
{
    List<CommunicationMethodUsageInformationDataType> usageInfoList = infoData.getUsageDatas();
    for(CommunicationMethodUsageInformationDataType methodUsage : usageInfoList)
    {
        if(methodUsage.isPublic())
        {
            List<CommunicationUsageTypeDataType> usageTypes = methodUsage.getTypeDatas();

            for(CommunicationUsageTypeDataType usageType : usageTypes)
            {
                if(usageType.isPrimary())
                {
                    CommunicationUsageTypeObjectType typeRefs = usageType.getTypeReference();
                    typeRefs.getIDS().stream()
                                             .filter(id -> id.getType().equals(WorkdayDataType.Communication_Usage_Type_ID)
                                                           && id.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("WORK"));
                            email = infoData.getEmailAddress();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

I have tried the following, but still unable to get the email:

```
emailInfoDataList.stream()
                         .peek(s -> s.getEmailAddress())
                         .flatMap(s -> s.getUsageDatas().stream())
                         .filter(s -> s.isPublic())
                         .flatMap(s -> s.getTypeDatas().stream())
                         .filter(s -> s.isPrimary())
                         .map(s -> s.getTypeReference())
                         .flatMap(s -> s.getIDS().stream())
                         .filter(s-> s.getType().equals(WorkdayDataType.Communication_Usage_Type_ID)
                                   && s.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("WORK"))
                         ;
```

Comment: 1) don't use `peek` to get a value, but use a terminal operator, e.g. `findFirst().orElse(...)`  2) don't flatMap everything as you are losing information as your scope get smaller and smaller, instead, stream the original list of usageDatas and if you are in the need for a filter that needs an inner loop, delegate to another method that will setup it's own stream and do the specific check

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But could you show me an example on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Summary**

Couple of things:

- use a terminal operator instead of `peek`, to find any email address we'll use `findAny`
- keep the stream at `EmailAddressInformationDataType` level to get the email addres from it if there is any found
- delegate the inspection to see if the user has a work address to the appropriate classes in order to get proper encapsulation and cleaner code

**Your `getEmail()` method**

Start at the top, we want a method that returns the email address if a work email address is found, if not we just return an empty string:

```
  private String getEmail() {
        return workerType.getWorkerData().getPersonalData().getContactData().getEmailAddressDatas().stream()
                         .filter(EmailAddressInformationDataType::hasWorkEmail)
                         .findAny()
                         .map(EmailAddressInformationDataType::getEmailAddress)
                         .orElse("");
  }
```

Remark that `findAny` returns an `Optional`. If you don't know how to use it, do some research, it's used here as a clean solution to either get the email address from the found `EmailAddressInformationDataType` or, if none found, the empty String is returned.

*Still to do*:

- clean up the long getter chain by extracting it to a method either on this class or in the `WorkerType` class
- maybe put the `hasWorkEmail` and `getEmailAddress` in a class as a static method receiving an `EmailAddressInformationDataType`. If you name the class `EmailAddress`, you can write `EmailAddress:hasWorkMail`, which is shorter and an easier read.

**The `hasWorkEmail()` method on `EmailAddressInformationDataType`**

the `EmailAddressInformationDataType` has a new method called `hasWorkEmail()`:

```
public boolean hasWorkEmail() {
    return getUsageDatas().stream()
                          .filter(CommunicationMethodUsageInformationDataType::isPublic)
                          .anyMatch(CommunicationMethodUsageInformationDataType::hasWorkEmail);
}
```

If you can't adjust the `-DataType` classes because they are generated, look at the previous remarks: move them to a static class `EmailAddress` with a method that accepts the `EmailAddressInformationDataType`. Remark that the `isPublic` method used here is just the existing one. Feel free to move the `isPublic` and `hasWorkEmail` again to a static method with a shorter name such as `CommunicationMethodUsage`, leaving all the boilerplate suffixes away.

**The `hasWorkEmail()` method on `CommunicationMethodUsageInformationDataType`**

Same story here, simple stream with mappings and filters. We use `anyMatch` to see if any email address is a work email address:

```
public boolean hasWorkEmail() {

    return getTypeDatas().stream()
                  .filter(CommunicationUsageTypeDataType::isPrimary)
                  .map(CommunicationUsageTypeDataType::getTypeReference)
                  .map(CommunicationUsageTypeObjectType::getIDS)
                  .flatMap(List::stream)
                  .filter(id -> id.getType().equals(WorkdayDataType.Communication_Usage_Type_ID))
                  .anyMatch(id -> "WORK".equalsIgnoreCase(id.getValue()));

}
```

This code compiles and works; it should give you a definite start on how to rewrite your code and tackle the rest of the codebase in the same manner.